# Accepting Nominations — Who should moderate this site?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Ideally, Moderators♦ are elected by the community, but until the community is large enough to hold a proper election, we will be appointing three provisional Moderators to fill those roles.

We need your help. Please nominate folks you would like to see become provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide valuable insight to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).**

### The Nomination Process:

- **Nominate a user** by posting an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Use the template at the bottom of this post to complete your nomination.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self-nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- **Tell us about the candidates.** Nominations can include links to other activities like Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **Nominees!** Please indicate your acceptance by editing the answer to accept/decline the nomination. And please ensure your profile email is correct so we can contact you. Optionally, you are encouraged to write a bit about yourself following your acceptance.

  > I accept/decline this nomination.
  >
  > Hi, I am name/location/fun fact (all optional). I live in <location>, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are…

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active during the earliest weeks of this site's creation
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

---

### Nomination Template

To nominate a candidate, copy and paste the text below as an answer and complete your nomination writeup:

> <a href="https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   <a href="https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   ###Notes:
>   This nominee would be a good choice because …

[image]

Comment: I really don't think this site is anywhere near being able to leave the private beta. In order to avoid becoming an internet wasteland, [this site needs to implement a back it up policy first](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182/why-doesnt-this-site-have-a-back-it-up-rule). Stack Exchange already has too many sites that don't make the internet a better place--I'm not referring to sites like Worldbuilding or Puzzling; I am referring to sites about topics that represent conventional uses of the SE platform but whose answers are, at best, based only off of Wikipedia.

Comment: What a wonderful community:  No downvotes for any of the nominees!

Comment: Hey Robert! Is this new? When we did the nominations for A&C they weren't until the site was a week into public beta. Is this going to be open until after the site is public or are you trying to get a mod team in place prior to going public?

Comment: @Catija Nope, not new. The nomination schedule is typically the last week of private through the first week or two of the public launch... unless I get backed up, or have another reason to believe it is better to wait.

Comment: Ah, ok! Just checked the dates again for A&C and I misread it. :D Thanks!

Comment: @gerrit Also great to see that everyone has accepted their nominations! (or nominated themselves), great to see so many people willing to help out :D

Comment: @gerrit Not anymore... I see two downvotes.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Is there any particular reason why you're still using an outdated screenshot of chrome's address bar? My thoughts are that it would be confusing to those people who actually need the picture to figure out the UserID.

Comment: @Ploni I don't think the brand of browser really matters, as not everyone here will be using chrome. As long as you know it's an address bar then anyone on any browser will be able to understand it.

Comment: That's strange that all the nominations have almost 3 downvote

Comment: @Ploni The screenshot is merely illustrative. It's not meant to denote any particular browser.

Comment: @AnkitSharma **If nominee(s) have down-voted everyone else in this thread,** it would not bode well for their appointment. At best it shows poor judgement; at worse it's voting abuse. Effective community-led moderation is the only thing keeping a site alive. If there are abuses from others acting in bad faith, they may find themselves no longer able to use these services.

Comment: @RobertCartaino A thought for your consideration. I think the norm is to have three pro-temps on a site, and with the experience SE, and the CM team, have with new sites, I suspect that it has been learned that such is the _magic number_. On this site, however, I believe that there will need to be one or two more than that. There will be times that a mod will need to _step back_ from situation, an may even need a couple other mods to remind them that it needs to be done. I want this site to succeed and I don't want to see the mods burn out trying to keep it cool. My 2¢, keep the change.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Just FYI, someone would have likely seen it in a timely manner without pinging someone for an immediate answer minutes after it was posted.

Comment: @RobertCartaino ok sure. I figured you were the only one who could answer it

Comment: Is the upvoting of this post how the mods will be chosen? Or will there be a separate post to actually vote on the mods?

Comment: @JoeS This is NOT an election. There is no second post. Post voting is simply another source of data and a show of support but does not directly decide who will be selected for a position. The nominees are suggestions to be considered by and selected by the Community Team at Stack Exchange. There will be a proper election for moderators at a [future date](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites).

Comment: @RobertCartaino Good to know :) So, when will the mods be chosen?

Comment: Looking forward to seeing who's chosen :)

Comment: @RobertCartaino can you give an indication of _when_ the mods will be chosen and announced?

Comment: @SQB early this coming week; Monday or Tuesday.

Answer (score 28):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

HDE 226868 would make a good moderator on Interpersonal Skills.  HDE has shown an early interest in the site and has (real and pro-tem) moderator experience elsewhere, which as far as I'm aware, people are quite satisfied with.  HDE has been active on meta and has a broad experience on the SE network.

A downside may be that HDE may be too busy to accept the nomination.

**I accept this nomination.**

I'm surprised and happy to have been nominated, and I'll be honored if I'm chosen as a pro-tem moderator. I'm currently a pro-tem mod on HSM and Mythology, and an elected mod on Worldbuilding. I'm on the east coast of the United States, so I'm typically online sometime from about 11:00 UTC - 3:00 UTC - with blocks offline for class, and other things.

I'm a college student currently studying astrophysics and math, by the way, but I'm also an avid runner, a music fan picking up trombone once again, and a voracious reader. I've found Interpersonal Skills to be a helpful resource so far for the real-life situations I have, and while I see places where we need to improve, I think we have plenty of potential for the future.

At the start of the private beta, I was really unsure of how things would turn out. I wasn't sure if the site would be a huge success or a disappointing failure. We're still at a point where only time will tell. But as the private beta went on, I became more and more encouraged (and so became more active). Given that I might have a shot at becoming a moderator here, I thought I should explain my additions to the Theory of Moderation:

- Moderators should be leaders when it comes to cross-site interactions (like migrations, when the system works) and communicating with others a bit about what the site is and how it works.
- Moderators should be welcoming to new community members (sans spammers and trolls, of course!). A community can always keep growing. As [I said in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/61165?m=38750922#38750922),

  > As we grow, it's going to be more important that we become a site for everyone, by everyone.

I've tried to work a bit in these areas already on this site, and I've seen plenty of others doing the same. I think Interpersonal Skills Stack Exchange has a bright future, no matter whether or not I moderate it.

Comment: Last time HDE was nominated for a pro-tem position, he declined due to being too busy. Hopefully he's found more time now and will be able to accept this nomination.

Comment: I appreciate the nomination, and I'll consider it. Things are a bit different for me now than they were under the circumstances @Randal'Thor's referring to (during the Literature private beta), so time might not be as much of an issue for me. I'll let you know when I decide to accept or decline the nomination, gerrit.

Comment: I support this. Though I am not really a user here, I have seen HDE's conduct, moderation, and participation in other sites to be great. He also has the added bonuses of 4th in meta participation here, 12k rep at MSE (thus a good understanding of how SE works in general), and a mod position at a graduated and beta site!

Answer (score 17):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

Catija has had a lot of participation here; she's currently the [#7 user by reputation](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) and also [one of the most active meta users](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation). She has a very good knowledge of the Stack Exchange system as a whole, with active participation on several larger and older sites and over 10k reputation on [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/). She's also already a moderator on [Arts & Crafts SE](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/users/52/), so she knows what it takes to be a good pro-tem mod.

Plus, look at that cute baby. Who wouldn't vote for that picture?

**I accept this nomination.**

Thank you, Rand, for the nomination and the kind words.

I've been thinking about whether I would consider moderating this site since before it went into Beta. That may sound odd but one of the things I like to think about is how "easy" or "difficult" I imagine a site would be to moderate. I think this site, particularly in Beta will be on the "difficult" end, largely because I think it needs a lot of direction and leadership in a way that the site I currently moderate (Arts & Crafts) really does not.

Fortunately, this site seems (even in private Beta) to have an amazingly engaged group of users who want to see it succeed and who are interested in making the site better and honing the scope and having active discussions on what is and is not on topic. I feel confident that the non-moderator users of this site, both the ones who don't get tapped from this nominations list and the users not interested in being diamonds here, will create a backbone that will help keep this site away from the danger zones of bad SE content.

I can not guarantee that I will always agree with everyone. We can't always shape a site the way we personally think it should be. But I will promise that, to the best of my ability, I will be happy to help keep this site on the tack we, as a group, choose to set it upon, whether as a moderator or not.

Some info about me. I work a day job that often allows me time to be on Stack Exchange throughout the day and am also an avid user of the iOS app - which has no moderation tools, unfortunately... I'm in chat most of the time, though I haven't been talking in *The Awkward Silence*, I did change the room name. I'm in the US on Central time, so I'm largely around here from 1500 Z - 300 Z.

As noted in the comments, please don't vote based on the cuteness of my avatar. I will continue to share the wealth of cuteness that is my small child even if I do not become a moderator of this site.

Comment: @Catija After that nomination, if your selected, you won't be able to *ever* change your avatar.  ;)

Comment: @anonymous2 Bah. I use photos of my baby all the time, just not the same ones. I'll change the image to a new, but still very cute photo of Ben and Hippo.

Comment: Election promise! Election promise!  You heard it!  ;)

Comment: @anonymous2 So that you don't have to vote for me based purely on wanting cute images of my baby, I promise to update my profile image regularly either way.

Comment: I mostly know Catija from Movies & TV.  She is a well-respected and knowledgeable contributor on that site.  She understands the SE system and has always shown good judgment in her decisions that help any SE community that she is involved in.  Good luck! :)  Oh...and she has the cutest baby EVER! ;)

Answer (score 14):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

This nominee would be a good choice because he is not only the top reputation earner as of this moment, but Crafter0800 has also been extremely active as an editor on the main site and on meta.  As of this writing, Crafter0800 has made 444 actions on the main site, and 84 on meta.  Both of these numbers are more than all of the other users nominated here (as of this writing) combined.  Crafter0800 has shown a real dedication to this site, and I believe that he will do an excellent job tending to it as a pro tem.

**I accept this nomination**

As for more about myself, my real name is Andrew (but I'd rather it if you refer to me as "Crafter" in posts though, to make things more understandable), I'm 17 years of age and currently reside in the UK. While I may not have much experience elsewhere on SE, I do have a large amount of experience on the forums (and in-game) of the [worlds largest Minecraft network](https://hypixel.net/forums/), with [my profile](https://hypixel.net/members/crafter0800.38175/) having a large number of posts. While I currently do not have the "Moderator" tag, I am currently a Moderator of the forums/network (currently on a 2-3 week break from Moderation duties, hence the lack of tag), which has provided me with some experience for this role. Besides, everyone has to start somewhere and I'd be delighted if I could start here on the Interpersonal skills SE. As you can imagine, one of my hobbies is visiting online forums such as this one, so there's that too.

I am based in the BST timezone, and am generally always free from 3PM - 9PM, however I can often be free all the way from 10AM - 9PM.

Comment: For some reason, I read that as "I am *banned* in the BST timezone" ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor can't blame you, I nearly misread it as that myself xD

Comment: @Crafter0800 your accept status should be come under notes. That is the format for nomination

Comment: I think you're awesome, the only reason I downvoted your nomination, is because you're still new to the site and I think it would be good if you were here for longer. I'm sure you'll make a great mod with more time here. This is just in regards to how the site works and for me I've always been cautious awarding people new to the site with too many privileges.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Everyone has to start somewhere.  A new site doesn't need **all** 3 mods to be veterans.  Having one mod as devoted to the site as Crafter0800 can only be a benefit. [*I usually aim for one topic expert, one network expert, and one chaos monkey...**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134980/280611) **-- Shog9**

Comment: @BenI. ah ok. In that case I'll reverse my vote.

Comment: @BenI. And here, I don't even know who the "topic expert" would be. I don't know that we have any "experts" in the sense of "professionals". :)

Comment: Any therapists around? Beuler? Beuler? ... As a group subjective metric, Crafter0800 has received the most rep, which is one indicator of topical knowledge. Though what you say is true. I just don't know what an expert exactly *is* in this field, so the subjective metric is probably a pretty reasonable one in this instance.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I just want to say thank you for informing me as to why you gave me a downvote, it's much appreciated :)

Comment: @Crafter0800 I have reversed it, since Ben posted that comment. I really like you and feel bad for being critical

Comment: @YvetteColomb No need to feel bad, especially when it comes to something as competitive as pro-tem mod elections, it can be hard to pick who you think would be best. I can totally understand why you down voted :)

Comment: @Crafter0800 I just voted for you :)

Comment: @YvetteColomb Thank you :D

Answer (score 13):

[image]
 
 [image]

#### Notes :

It is in my nature to always try to help. I have done this both on my job and in life in general. As such, I am simply volunteering to be a moderator because I believe I can help this site. I would be perfectly happy if other like-minded people are selected, but to help ensure that happens, here I am.

I am and have been active on this site and others. I have been here every day several times a day, and that will continue into the future – just as I have done on several other sites.

Regardless, I will still assist in the review queues, in helping to formulate consensus on our Meta, and whatever else comes our way on this site. I am glad I am here.

Comment: I know John mainly from [movies.se], where he always stood out for his comments providing helpful and sensible feedback to new users while also coming across as super-friendly and not patronising or standoffish. This speaks volumes for both his interpersonal skills and his suitability as a moderator.

Comment: @Randal'Thor fully agreed with that

Comment: Yes!  I totally agree with @Randal'Thor!  John has proven to be a valued contributor on Movies & TV.  He has always been extremely helpful and very friendly and welcoming to new users.  He would be an asset as a mod to any community :)

Comment: I voted for John, I think he's be a great mod. I can't understand how this nomination got any downvotes.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

[image]

---

#### Notes:

Hello there! I'm Zizouz212! I would love to have the opportunity to serve as a moderator for IPS!

I've self-nominated myself much later here because I wanted to be more confident and see where the direction of the site is going. Although we've already had some blips and bleeps here and there, I really like the community and the way we are propelling the site forward.

I'm a soon-to-be university student about to study global development policy up in my nation's capital, and I can definitely say that interpersonal skills and cross-cultural communication is a big part of that. Culture and society has always been an interest of mine, and living in the multicultural city of Toronto has always exposed me to a vast array of world cultures. As I navigate myself ahead, I will really enjoy have this site as a resource for whenever I may need assistance.

For the position, I [already have moderator experience](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/users/69/zizouz212?tab=profile), so I'm already familiar with the moderator tools, and how sites across the network run. Community members who have talked to me in chat, or read my posts on meta know that I'm a big supporter of cultural relativism on this site. I believe that it's a key thing (in addition to other policies), that when working together will secure the success of this site.

My participation on the site has been much less than I wanted - the site's private beta started during my exam week, which was quickly followed by Canada's 150th birthday and many religious holidays - so I've taken more of an observer role during my time here, voting on questions and answers while providing feedback and opinions to other members.

Best of luck to all! I know that however this all goes, that the community will always put its best foot forward :)

Comment: see [people do like you](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39146592#39146592) :D I voted for your blue avatar!

Answer (score 9):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I think Yvette would be a good choice for a few reasons:

- She's been active on both the main site and meta *consistently*. Other folks have more posts than she does on main, but in both cases, Yvette has spread her activity out over time. A good pro tem mod should be committed to stay with the site for a while, and I think her continued interest shows that she would be such a choice.
- She participates on meta! Honestly, that's something that is occasionally overlook. Yvette has both raised discussion issues and given her opinions on them - and, of course, cast quite a few votes.
- She's active in chat. That's certainly not a requirement for modship, but it proves one thing, which is that she's ready and willing to talk to folks about issues. Communication is key for a moderator, and an openness to communication is a great sign.
- Yvette has some moderator experience on [Pets Stack Exchange](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/6796/yvette-colomb). I know she's only been on the job for a month, so I understand if she's not yet ready to take on another site, but her previous participation there shows an aptitude for community moderation.
- She's also involved with [Charcoal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) by the way.

---

**I decline this nomination**

I have nominated myself for [moderator on StackOverflow (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/election/9) and, although I may not be elected there, I do not think it is fair to have a foot in both camps. Besides we have enough excellent candidates for mod here, so my nomination will not be missed.

[I came 3rd](https://www.opavote.com/results/5927932925050880/0) and may be called up - but will run again. Besides SO is my main love on the Stack Exchange network and having a modship on Pets.Se with my contributions on SO is enough.

---

*Older considerations:*

Thanks for the nomination and support HDE 226868. I apologise for taking so long to reply, as I was giving this much consideration. As mentioned, I've recently been made mod on [Pets.Se](https://pets.stackexchange.com/) and was contemplating what sort of work load it would be moderating this site into public Beta.

The Pets site is small and the moderation duties are almost effortless. I check in on the site many times during the day, as I do this site. I check the feed in chat for new questions, both on the main site and meta and look at new answers - for both Pets and Interpersonal Skills.

I've regularly been checking the review queues on this site.

I've reviewed the:

- [second most close posts](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats)
- [third most first posts](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/stats) ([Robert Cartaino](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/3/robert-cartaino) has reviewed the most, as he was the only one with privileges when the site started.)
- [third most reopen votes](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/stats)
- am mid way through the [suggested edit reviews](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/stats)

I've made [59 suggested edits](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/57/yvette-colomb?tab=activity), many on tag wikis and excerpts, most of which have been approved.

I've cast [93 votes](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/57/yvette-colomb?tab=summary) on the main site and am [the most frequent attender](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/61165/the-awkward-silence) of the site's chat room, The Awkward Silence.

I may not be the most high rep user ([I ranked as 11th overall](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)), but I think this is a good thing, as I've deliberately focused on moderating the site, as I find this interesting. Having said that, I have also discussed and focused on what content is on topic, participating in both meta and the chat room.

I work from home and have access to the site any time I am online. I check in over a 16-18 hour period, for reviews and would do the same for flags. I'm in AEST so serve as a good foil to most people who are available at differing timezones.

I've been active on Stack Exchange for some years now and am a member of the [Charcoal team](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) and [the SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). I've also participated on Stack Exchange Meta, from before it was separated from StackOverflow.

With the intent of full disclosure, I've had a long history with Stack Exchange, [not all good.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293213/why-dont-we-keep-public-records-of-suspensions/293335#293335) If you read my [moderation nomination for Pets.Se](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2169/6796), you'll see I take moderator positions seriously and as a responsibility to the community and our larger site. It is an honoured position.

I've proven to be a reliable and consistent user of the site and would make a consistent, reliable and responsible moderator.

Thank you for considering me and taking the time to read this and all the linked posts.

*update*
I've been [automatically made room owner](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38776745#38776745) of our site's chatroom. Which means, I've been the most [frequent attender of the chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#automatic-owner).

> The system will pick the room's most active user in this case and make them owner;

**Caveat:**

I have nominated myself on [StackOverflow as Moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/election/9). If, by chance, I am elected, I will to withdraw my nomination here, as it will be stretching myself too thin.

Comment: I'm curious to have feedback for the downvotes. It's always good to know where I'm going wrong

Comment: @YvetteColomb I foresee many times that people will be receiving downvotes that make no sense. I realize that SE uses votes for a first line of defense at moderation, and that users of this site are likely to be extra sensitive to vote results. One of the big challenges for mods of this site will be rising above the vote sensitivity. Many of us are here because we know we have some social skills problems, but knowing that may not some of us from proving it in little ways while we're here. From my own observations and readings here, I really believe that you (and HDE) can rise to the challenge.

Comment: @WitanapDanu well said. I agree about rising above vote sensitivity, but I really do want to know. And yes, online communication and the very nature of this site - plus we're flooded with programmers, who have a reputation for not always being the best socially -whether or not that's a truism, I know it's true for me

Comment: Rather than worry about what someone might have taken offense to, but not enough to mention it, just focus on being your best and doing what you think is right for the site. Perhaps they will speak up later, or perhaps not. With what I seem to recall, you should have the tools you need. Concentrate on helping others that are ready, and allow those not ready to have their private thrills that don't really matter anyway. Lyrics of a song I like has _it's not my style to worry 'bout something when something may be something thats nothing at all._

Comment: Let's go to chat - I want to know what that song is :)

Comment: @YvetteColomb Re your latest edit - won't the IPS mods be chosen before the SO election is over?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Firstly I think it's unlikely I'll be chosen here - the votes speak for themselves. Secondly They will be delayed by an extra week in selecting the mods here https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/220/57 Whereas the SO election will finish 1st August. It should be done and dusted before they've finalised these. I'm thinking I might withdraw my nomination here and focus on SO

Comment: @YvetteColomb you might want to edit this to better reflect your current position (came in third, on stand-by on SO).

Comment: @SQB yeh, and if I don't get elected this time - I will run again - either way - I want to spend more time on SO. So only want one satellite modship - Pet.se. It was fun being a part of the launch here. It's an interesting site and really difficult to define scope .. I'll edit

Comment: I've noticed your edit and the rollback. **STAY!** Don't abandon us.

Comment: @NVZ no I'm not - I realise I really have some poor interpersonal skills - I need this site!!

Answer (score 8):

[image]

[image]

[image: profile for NVZ on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

I'm NVZ, and I'd like to volunteer for this.

Although I'm fairly new to this particular community, I'd say, **my transferable skills and experience from other communities are what make me a worthy candidate**.

I'm a [high reputation user](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/50044/nvz?tab=reputation), a top flagger, [editor](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/50044/nvz?tab=activity&sort=revisions), voter and [reviewer](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/50044/nvz?tab=activity&sort=reviews), and I've got **all** the moderation [badges](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/50044/nvz?tab=badges) on English Language and Usage, and I'm also currently a top participant on [its meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/50044/nvz).

I'm [nice](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) to everyone, and I follow the [theory of moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/), and I've even participated in the [elections on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/election/4#post-341874) (lost in the final stage).

If I'm given the chance, I'd make the best of it, and I'd work with the other mods and reviewers to keep this community a great environment for learning and sharing knowledge.

If required, ask the mods on ELU, and I'm confident that they'll have only good things to say about me.

---

Offline, I've got a master's in civil engineering (work in project management), and I'm a non-resident Indian living in the Middle East (in Dubai, currently) since the beginning of time.

I may not ask or answer questions on the main site much, but I'll answer queries on meta, and I'll be here as a human exception handler (you know, a silent guardian, watchful protector, of sorts).

Comment: there is a format for this. that's why I added the flair. the network flair should not be placed with the site flair

Comment: @SagarV Okay, so, I've put it below instead of at the top.

Comment: Do you have any reasons for why you would be a good moderator for this site in particular? You're only been here for about a day, and no matter what your other skills are, or expertise on other sites, that kinda outweighs your other advantages.

Comment: NVZ, minor point, but I put your flair at the top so we have a consistent format. Before there was a "format", folks started to embellish their nomination with all sorts of *fluff* simply to draw attention, and it quickly became *inapt.*

Comment: @HDE226868 That's a valid point, and I'm well aware of my shortcomings in this community. My overall network experience (4 years) and moderation skills (I was so close to being elected on ELU) are important factors in being a good moderator here. In terms of reputation here, I have not asked or answered any questions yet.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Thanks. It was at the top at first. I was told by another user to take it down.

Comment: The third is optional, not a big deal.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Quick question: Is it mandatory to have participated in a particular community to nominate myself there? Or is it enough that I have experience in moderating elsewhere (as a regular user without diamonds)?

Comment: Moderators are selected from and representative of the community by definition, so familiarity with the site and the community would be important.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Thanks, and I guess that disqualifies me in a way. :( But I'll keep the nomination anyway. Sportsmanship :)

Comment: Everyone is welcome... with [rare exceptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year).

Comment: I joined this site interpersonal.SE (which I heard of only today) not only to wholeheartedly support the candidature of NVZ but because this is a fascinating subject and it's something wonderful that we now have a Stack Exchange community dedicated to the intricacies of interpersonal interactions. I am new to Stack Exchange myself, having joined English Language and Usage only 3 months ago, but after intensive interaction with NVZ I can confirm that NVZ has all the skills and experience of a moderator: most crucially NVZ has the even temperament and strong maturity that makes a good moderator.

Comment: @NVZ I greatly appreciate your wish to be a moderator at Interpersonal.SE -- you are one of the nicest and most helpful senior members of English.SE and ideally suited to be a major contributor at Interpersonal as well: even if your experience here is limited at present, I fully expect you to be active enough here and enough of a valuable member by the time the next moderator elections come around: and I am certain you will sooner or later become a moderator of Interpersonal.SE!

Comment: @EnglishStudent Thank you. That means a lot. :)

Comment: @NVZ you deserve it!

Comment: I fully support NVZ being a moderator. NVZ, you are a guiding light for me on English.SE, and *are* always fair and nice. I think you deserve moderatorship completely! Good luck :)

Comment: I too support NVZ being a moderator. He/she seems to always be the first person to comment on every question, either helping the user out or just keeping things light. NVZ is the perfect example of a moderator.

Comment: NVZ would be a good moderator.  He is a voice of reason on ELU Meta, (where things occasionally get contentious) and has close acquaintainship with several cultures.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I committed to this site proposal and have been participating since it's launch as private beta. I am active in Q/A and have been reviewing posts since then. Though I am not too active on meta, but I keep visiting it on daily basis.

I am active on other sites as well, reviewing posts and help learning newcomers use of the site, mainly [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/27264/a-j?tab=profile). I have edited more than 1400 posts and raised more than 1300 helpful flags on Stack Exchange Network. I visit Stack Exchange every day and am active on site more than 8 hours a day.

I am also frequent in chat and always available in [The Screening Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/the-screening-room), [The Awkward Silence](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61165/the-awkward-silence), and [The Reading Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1037/the-reading-room).

I have been moderating the sites to maintain and keep them clean with the privileges I have earned through reputation. I am volunteering for moderator position because I believe that I can help more with additional privileges.

Comment: I only know AJ from Movies & TV.  He is a valued contributor and is extremely active in chat and always willing to help new users.  He understands how SE works and is always striving for excellence in the SE community.  Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I would like to be a mod since I really believe that I could make a difference, I was not active at first as other items (in real life) were more pressing. I am active on PPCG another Stack Exchange and would like to help everyone here change for the better. I know that I only have 177 reputation here. I do the things that need to be done, not the the tasks that I want to do. I spent weeks flagging answers, questions, comments on Stack Overflow, just to help out the moderators. I know my reputation may be small but don't let that discourage you.

I strive to always accept mistakes. When my mistakes are pointed out I fix them. I would be a "down to earth" moderator. Interacting with everyone as a person, not just a username and password. I strive to always improve and think that I could help this community grow and become a large stackexchange. Thank you for you time and consideration

-Christopher

Comment: I am generally seen from 8 to 8 EST on and off.

Comment: I've downvoted you as [your activity here is poor](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/117/christopher?tab=activity&sort=all) and I think a mod should be elected on their performance on the site, not awarded the privileges on a promise that they will use them well.

Comment: @YvetteColomb i just put myself here to say I did it XD

Comment: aww, I actually felt bad when I left that comment, because it doesn't mean that you wouldn't make a good mod, it's just the criteria I look for :)

Comment: @YvetteColomb yeah I never thought i would actually be a mod. Just felt like doing it :P i mean how often can one run for mod :P

Comment: Anyways i understood why you would downvote

Comment: I reversed my downvote :)

Comment: @YvetteColomb lol -1!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

Hi All, I am nominating myself. Please guys don't demotivate me just because I am new here, Support me just because of I have more than 6 years experience on all over the Stack Exchange websites. I know very well what a moderator should do with which limitations.

You can see my profile on Stackoverflow here:

[image]

And my overall exposure on Stack Exchange is here:

[image]

So Above flairs demonstrated my presence on all over websites. Please guys review my profile everywhere first, asking any question to me.

### **Why Me:**

Here are the points:

- Polite
- Have patience
- Available more than 5 hours
- Supportive
- Talkative (When Necessary)

My thinking is: *Self praise is no recommendation*.

So anybody want to ask any question to me. Feel free to ask. I will surely reply.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes

Myself Sagar V, a front end developer working in a city far away from my native.

My timezone is IST (GMT+0530)

I participated throughout the area51 proposal and an active participant here throughout the beta phase.

#### 8 in all time users based on rep

#### Why me

- I am here in Stack Exchange network for more than 4 years and have a good understanding of how the system works(I believe so).
- #### I am spending more than 11 hours in Stack Exchange sites.(from 10 AM to  9.30 PM)

So, you can contact me regarding any problem in moderation.

Using privileges wisely.

I have Close Vote privilege in Stack Overflow and using it wisely and spend almost 40 Close Votes per day.

Mainly I spend time to review items, Close questions, reopen questions, add comments to clarify the posts, cast votes, raise flags. I am not a rep hunter.

My main site is Stack Overflow. I reviewed more than 1500 items there, edited more than 500 posts and casted more than 1.1K votes.

My secondary-active site is Meta Stack Exchange.

But I am taking care of this site in a special basis because this is in beta phase and need more attention.

- ## Be polite

My policy will be always be polite

- Ready to help

Ready to help anyone regarding anything.

- Accept mistakes and change accordingly

I have changed a lot by the moderators on Stack Overflow and I really thank them for that.

Here is my Stack Overflow flair and network flair

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes here. What's going on?

Comment: @NVZ - Possibly concern over their poor grasp of written English

Answer (score -1):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I believe I would be a good choice because I've been around the network for a good few years and I think I have a fair and balanced idea of, not only how moderation works, but also how the Stack Exchange model works.

I started out on Stack Overflow four and a half years ago, and Stack Exchange has been a part of my daily routine ever since.

I also spend nearly as much time on meta as I do on the main pages. I think my posts on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/217863/apaul34208) probably say a bit about the sort of moderator I would be. I strongly believe that the community should set it's own policies and norms through meta, moderators don't get to make up the rules single handedly.

I'm not always right, but I'm usually pretty quick to admit that. I'm also not afraid to take an unpopular stand once in a while.

For the most part I believe moderators should be exception handlers. Moderators step in and clean up the few things that community can't handle on it's own. More [janitors](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/20048/15062) than security guards or bouncers.

Comment: I'd support you as a moderator here. I've seen you around the traps and I think you'd do a good job

Comment: @Yvette Colomb thanks, for the support. I figured it was about time I stepped up. Best of luck to you in the SO race.

Comment: thanks, it's been a huge move. I hope I'm elected. I think I will step up and do SO proud. :)

Comment: apaul34208 seems like a good candidate for moderator. He has shown he's committed to the success of this site, as well as the network in general (he's done a lot on Meta Stack Exchange).

Comment: I just don't understand the downvotes on this.

Comment: @Yvette Colomb Well, I suppose a couple people thought I would be a good fit and a couple others disagreed. I'm not too worried about it, people are entitled to their opinions.