# When are we going to public beta? — DONE!

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, moderation, beta

I'm wondering when it's expected we will go into public beta. There's been a bit of chat about it and speculation. It would be good to know.

We have the moderator nominations up [Accepting Nominations — Who should moderate this site?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187/accepting-nominations-who-should-moderate-this-site?cb=1) and I assume, we will need the moderators active before the site goes public?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the site is in public β.

Comment: @gerrit it's not off topic - it's status complete - if anything

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### This site is now public. Enjoy!

---

*Original answer:*

Barring any technical delays, the site should go public tomorrow afternoon (Tue, 18-Jul). The nomination thread was posted last week, so the selection process typically begins about a week *after* the site launches; however, I will be out of town next week and I am slated to make the initial contacts, so we might have to delay the final selections until the following week. That is not unusual.

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you to the Stack Exchange team for helping get this site off the ground. It plenty of potential to deeply help people on an individual level, and I'm thankful that we've gotten the chance to dip into that potential.

Comment: ^ similar thoughts here. This was not an easy proposal, I quite worried even during commitment if it's going to fall, but you somehow managed to make it a healthy SE site and it couldn't have been possible withough either of us.