# Is asking for a definition or a general perception in matters of interpersonal relationships on topic?

Tags: discussion

Some examples:

- What are core values?
- Why don't just call them values instead of core values?
- What are opposite values?
- Are honesty and friendship/family opposite values?
- Why they say opposite values are complementary?

...and I can go on and on.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by "values"?

Comment: @HDE226868 that is precisely my point, it kinds of begs the question.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with how you interact with a specific person in a specific situation?

Comment: @NVZ No, just for academic porposes. I think this is the closest SE site to deal with those thinks, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Other than the definitions from general references, what would you expect to find? Our opinions on those definitions?

Comment: **I don't think we're here to define things**. So, it's most likely off-topic.

Comment: Try asking this on [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61165/the-awkward-silence) as well. Maybe there's more to this. A discussion may help.

Comment: @NVZ I see... this site is completely different to what I'm accustomed to see in the SE network, I'm just testing the waters. Values are very important for philosophers, but some values aren't clearly defined or lack cultural references, that's why I asked in the first place. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I do remember that there was an Anthropology site proposal somewhere on Area 51 - it may interest you to follow and support it since these are all anthropological questions.

Comment: @Zizouz212 I think I was following it, but it was [deleted](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94538/anthropology).

Comment: Aw shucks. I was really hoping that would succeed :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Off-topic

We don't have to define things here. We expect questions that are about navigating through tough life situations when dealing with other human beings.

Such definition requests are probably suited to other sites on the network.

If the answers you expect are too philosophical, then it's off-topic on English Language and Usage as well - that I can guarantee you.

Comment: I got it! I think those are't for SE Philosophy either, because of the need for cultural references.

Comment: @rraallvv there's [philosophy.se], for one. But I'm not familiar with that site.

Answer (score -1):

## No

This site is not, nor should it be, an academic site. We're here to focus on practical [experience-based](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1267/288) solutions to practical problems. You'll need to propose a new site on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) if you want to ask social science questions on Stack Exchange.