# Wrong earned Badge dialog

Tags: bug, badges

I just noticed that I earned a new badge on the Meta side of my account (not sure if that's the right way to articulate the difference). I visited my Meta profile to learn more: "Congratulations, you've earned the Teacher badge."

When I clicked the black badge in that announcement, the little drop-down info reminded that the Teacher badge is awarded for "Answer a question with score of 1 or more," but after "Awarded for:" was a link to a Question I asked, not an Answer. To be clear, I did not also answer that question.

[image]

[image]

On the plus side, the blue Learn More button took me to a page that *did* show the correct information – it showed the Question to which I did provide an Answer that received a +, for which I received the Teacher badge.

[image]

The bug I'm reporting is that the little drop-down info box you get when you click on a newly earned badge may not give the correct info.

Comment: If you're able to replicate this with another badge, please take a screenshot if possible and post it with the question. As outsiders we'll only see the correct information as @gerrit has pointed out in the answer.

Comment: @BradleyWilson Actually, I haven't earned any new ones since then, so I was able to take the screenshots you requested. Thanks. Good idea!

Answer (score 1):

You earned it for [your answer here](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/should-we-step-up-our-voting-culture/1420#1420).

Not sure why you are seeing something else.

[image: screenshot of badge page]