# What is the site recommendation for citations and references when we post an answer here?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I am new to the whole concept of Stack Exchange and mainly active at English Language and Usage since April 2017. Now English.SE is a site that depends heavily on citations and references to support our answers. How does Interpersonal.SE approach this? I ask because I should like to post answers here but I am not sure that references/citations could be found to back up points made in our answers in the interpersonal realm, (which is more cultural than scientific, though *very* important, IMHO) except by quoting the published opinions of other persons. If the site has specific policy regarding references, I shall certainly prepare my answers accordingly.

Related meta question: [Do we want references in our answers?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/do-we-want-references-in-our-answers)

Comment: Related: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83/should-we-encourage-writing-from-experience and https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182/why-doesnt-this-site-have-a-back-it-up-rule I know that the second one doesn't have an answer at this point but I wonder if these two questions between them (plus the one you've linked) already address the question you're asking here?

Comment: Thanks for the links @Catija the 2 meta articles along with the one I linked in my question do seem to stress the need to write *either* from personal experience or quoting reliable references.

Comment: There's certainly room for doing both, which is what I try to do when I can. Sometimes it's difficult to find supporting documentation. What (I think) we really don't want is people spit-balling ideas that aren't tested at all.

Comment: @Catija very true. Documentation may not always be available but I am sure community wisdom can deal with an insincere or speculative answer through comments and downvotes.