# Comment deletion on an off-topic question that may be about genuine crisis

Tags: discussion, comments

I understand that TaraNicotiana’s recent [question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/15182/how-to-get-out-of-a-dysfunctional-living-situation-with-irregular-circumstances) about how to get out of a dysfunctional living situation was off-topic, I have no quibble with it being on hold.

However, if Tara’s account is true then she is living in a situation where she seems unable to exercise basic rights such as access to her personal identity documents and freedom of movement and association.

Although I understand it was outside the scope of what comments are intended for, I posted her some advice on getting replacement identity documents and a link to Scottish Women’s Aid, a resource for women in danger in Scotland.

That comment has been removed and I would like to understand why, especially as there doesn’t seem to have been a general comment cull.

I am genuinely concerned by this person’s account and situation and very worried in case she is unaware that she can reach out for help and get replacement documents.

- So, why was the particular comment removed?
- What is the stack policy for handling situations where a poster reveals that they may be living in an abusive setting, whether that be physical or psychological?

Comment: I'm of the same mind and so will refrain from making an answer. I understand that it's not our purpose of this stack to actually answer the questions this person had, but short of that there is a *lot* that can be done to help this person. If we can help this person see through the veil of their apparent Stockholm syndrome for even a moment, I think we can do a world of good, and afterwards we can clean the whole thing up.

Comment: Thank you Cronax

Comment: I had a similar [question](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2818/how-should-we-handle-questions-where-it-is-suspected-the-op-is-being-abused) a while ago.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your comment was flagged as No Longer Needed along with others. I was the moderator who handled these comment flags. Since your comment was not suggesting improvements or asking for clarifications, it was removed.

Though, this may be an exceptional case where such comment can be allowed. If an OP is asking for professional help or in need of professional help, a comment referring to professional help only can be allowed here. This is true for abuse just as much as suicide.

From [an IPS meta post](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2903/29),

> **But a comment is always good, as long as it is linking the OP to further, professional help, instead of just an opinion on the matter, or a half-written comment-answer.**

This is my fault and I have undeleted your comment.

> What is the stack policy for handling situations where a poster reveals that they may be living in an abusive setting, whether that be physical or psychological?

In such cases, all we can do is to refer them to professionals who are expert in handling such things. If the conditions are worse, it can [be escalated](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6258/287703) to community managers.

Comment: Thank you for a very considered response.

Comment: out of curiosity, why didn't you think about this earlier?

Comment: @Ooker I have explained this in the first paragraph.