# How is this not an interpersonal answer?

Tags: discussion

For this [post](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/8255/should-i-let-my-wifes-little-brother-win-at-chess/8256?noredirect=1#comment31918_8256) I answered spot a queen and play full.

It was deleted by a mod as not an interpersonal answer.

How is that not an interpersonal answer?

Level the field and not let them win is interpersonal.  It is a direct answer to the stated question.

Comment: I flagged it as *very low quality*.

Answer (score 5):

I was the mod who cast the second delete vote (a community member had already voted to delete the answer). My wording for the comment I wrote afterwards was

> Please only post answers that are interpersonal solutions to the question asked; this does not address the question.

My thought process was basically "Well, the question asks whether or not the OP should intentionally lose, not what sort of opening he should make in the game." I would argue that saying "Do moves leading to [X, Y, Z]" or somesuch aren't interpersonal. A good interpersonal answer would talk about how the other person would feel about the situation.

What I *should* have said was that it's a low-quality answer; you didn't give any reasons why your answer was a good one or why you think it works. This is [the sort of thing we delete](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2003/102). Therefore, your answer was deleted. If you edit it and flag it for undeletion using a custom flag, then it may be undeleted.

All of that said, I should add that the question, in its current form, is not a fantastic one - not terrible, but a yes-or-no question, and so it's currently on hold as primarily opinion-based. The interpersonality of the situation is debatable, I feel; we'll see how things look if the OP edits it.

Comment: I consider handicap to make the field more level to very much address interpersonal but not going to argue with you.  OP brought up not playing all out to intentionally lose so not getting how an opening is that far off.

Comment: I've switched the question to a dupe of an existing one based on the feedback of the OP. :D

Comment: @Paparazzi What you explained in your comment makes for a better IPS answer than just providing specific chess moves/lingo.  Your answer as it was is valid as an answer for something more along the lines of a chess forum, but not an IPS forum.  In any answer, more detail as to *why* actions should be taken is helpful and betters your chances of your post being upvoted/accepted/not removed.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the lack of applicable interpersonal skills, there's also the extremely brief unexplained answer issue...

I'm bringing it up here because this is an issue that you've been approached about several times, and each time you seem to refuse to edit to improve or expand on your posts.

> Do X.

May be an *answer*, but it's a very low quality answer. And it's a style we've been actively trying to avoid on this stack. I know those slide on other sites, but they don't slide here. The nature of interpersonal skills, being nuanced, kind of requires answers to address things like context; ***why*** you should "Do X" is often as important, if not more important, that the suggested solution.

It's a matter of helping the OP understand why your answer is an answer, rather than a suggestion pulled out of thin air and/or opinion. The ***why*** also helps future readers determine if the answer will be applicable to their similar, but not exactly the same, situation.

Comment: Not much use to edit a deleted post.

Comment: @Paparazzi there's use to edit a deleted answer: bring it into a real answer and ask (flag) for un-deletion, this should help to avoid an answer ban, if too much of your answers get deleted then somewhere in time you'll be blocked from answering.see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105116/sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-answers-from-this-account/105119#105119)

Comment: Alternatively, don't write [one-line answers](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/should-we-be-more-strict-about-one-line-answers) in the first place.

Comment: This does not address the stated question.

Comment: @Paparazzi just thought it worthwhile to point out that a 2 sentence IPS answer would have been deleted as well.

Comment: @apaul You don't run the site.

Comment: The community runs the site, for the most part, and I'm a member of the community. If you would prefer to be able to write 2 sentence answers, feel free to ask a new meta question about that, but I doubt it'll gain much traction. @Paparazzi

Comment: @apaul Moving on