# Interpersonal skills site & opening rules for subjectivity questions

Tags: discussion

I recently stumbled across our interpersonal skills site and asked a question that involves some opinions. One of our helpful members of that site helped modify my question so that it fits our guidelines better, but I can't help to think - isn't interpersonal skills / relationships inherently subjective and opinion based? Do you think rules should be modified for more empirical fields of study where often times, any answer really is inherently an opinion regardless of how you try framing it?

Comment: You've hit on a question that has been asked of this site [since the beginning](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1421/is-this-site-essentially-a-centre-for-primarily-opinion-based-questions) - the short answer is, this is why we have strict [answer guidelines](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3583/what-are-the-citation-expectations-of-answers-on-ips-stack-exchange) ;) I'm not sure what you mean about rules being modified though, could you explain more about that?

Comment: My personal opinion is yes, interpersonal skills and relationships are clearly inherently subjective.  That doesn't mean that we can't judge answers or ask that answers be backed up, but clearly whether an answer works for someone depends on that particular individual.

Comment: The part that isn't immediately visible to newcomers is the long and arduous process that has been undertaken to arrive at the current rules. Speculating on that a bit, it causes a bit of "sunk cost" fallacies in the community, the rules are good because we have invested so much in them. Personally there are a few of them I would loosen up a little, one of them is the absolute demand on referring a direct personal experience (or cited works). A good answer is a good answer -  most answers get better with a reference - but deleting a good answer out of lack of one is a loss. IMHO, YMMV.

Comment: I think it will help if we have separate guidelines for empirical based disciplines. Sometimes, things that help people the most with relationships isn't so much about a correlation between action and results, but rather, a consideration of a variety of opinions and picking the best out of them for any given situation. There are always going to be individual differences because people are people, and we have different personalities, preferences, tolerance to abuse, and etc. If we can relax guidelines / make them tiered somehow, I felt like that will be ideal.