# Community wiki questions on IPS

Tags: discussion, questions, community-wiki

Could it be possible to create some community wiki questions on common interpersonal problems with several possible solutions?

**For example**

Question : How to meet new people ?
Possible answers : join a hobby club, volunteer at your local hospital, use the *** app, join a D&D group, etc.

Question : What activities are appropriate for a first date ?
Possible answers : Movie-going, birdwatching, restaurant, coffee, etc.

Question : How to integrate better at a new job ?
Possible answers : Bring cookies, join the fantasy football team, etc.

---

From what I understand, in community wiki questions each answer must contain only one solution to the problem, it's possible for a user to post multiple answers, and the "accepted" one is usually a list of all the others. Since some problems are very common, though everyone's situation is different, that kind of question could be useful here.
(I know there are only a *very few* questions that could be appropriate for this)

Are community wiki questions accepted on IPS?
Is there a mod who would accept to create some ?

Comment: Why the downvote ? Is there a part of this question I should improve ? (Note : English isn't my first language, I'm sorry if I didn't express myself clearly enough or too abruptly).

Comment: See this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191880) for an explanation on the meaning of votes on meta.

Comment: @AnneDaunted Thank you! :) "On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement" Should I add the "feature-request" tag then?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to add that tag. I guess the DV just means that they disagree with the idea of having community wiki questions on IPS.

Comment: @AnneDaunted Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On IPS, we're all about the details - details for the cultural setting of the problem, the circumstances under which it is taking place, the particulars of the people involved, etc. We really need each asker to tailor the question specifically to their circumstances, so they can get the best possible answers from the community. After all, [solutions in one setting might not work in another](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1254/102).

Community wiki questions are sort of antithetical to this basic concept. Answers would have to be vague and generic, and so you get to the point where you try to help everyone and end up helping nobody. That's obviously not great.

Besides, there's not necessarily a need for every solution. Let's only worry about restaurant etiquette in Suriname when someone in Suriname asks about it. Otherwise, you'd end up with community wiki questions with scores of answers - most of them unnecessary. I say we address needs as they come up, not before.

Comment: My thinking was that there are a few (not all) questions that can help several people, like for the "how to meet new people?" question, some answers may only be applicable in specific countries, but at the end it's a fairly common problem, so it could be helpfull for both users and non-users to have one question instead of several. But I understand that IPS works differently than the other Stack Exchange sites.