# Should users be approached with a comment about improving old answers?

Tags: discussion

I understand the desire/need for moderation and to have a certain standard, but I think going through old posts and asking users to improve answers that are over a year old based on rules implemented months after the answer was posted is ridiculous.

Deleting comments replying to said requests is also rude and a good way to drive users away from the site.

Link to answer/comment requesting edit.
https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/78421?noredirect=1

Comment: If this is about a specific post, could you provide a link to that post?

Comment: @scohe001 Yes.  Edited question to include

Answer (score 4):

The consensus here on meta (as shown in the proposed [dupe target](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2336/should-we-be-deleting-old-answers-that-dont-meet-our-new-standards)) is that when new insights produce new rules or policies, older posts need to be held against those new standards.

That gives us two options for posts that don't suffice anymore:

1. Delete them
2. Approach the user to give them the chance to improve their post, before 1) happens.

Number 2 happened here, and given the meta I linked above, that seems like a nice courtesy.