# What to do with this question? To edit or not to edit?

Tags: discussion

[With regard to the whole dicussion about what we allow here and what not:](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2077/1599)

What do we do with questions like [this?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/6737/1599)

Magisch already suggested an improvement in the [comments](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/6737/1599).

I'm personally thinking that for this paragraph:

> It's not that she's at all rude about it; she isn't. However, her pronunciation is just plain wrong to me, and I can't be untrue to myself by pronouncing it her way. Besides, I never even remember. You can't memorize every little detail about everybody you work with. People pronounce my last name wrong all the time (it's not really Plunkett).

Both 'I can't be untrue to myself by pronouncing it her way' and 'You can't memorize every little detail about everybody you work with' are what's leading to the downvotes and comment discussion underneath the question?

I was thinking of just stepping in and editing them out, but I'm not sure whether I would be overstepping a boundary? So, what do we do here, just suggest them in a comment like Magisch did or step in and edit?

Comment: *In dubio contra emendo* (sorry for my bad latin)

Comment: I don't speak Latin at all, so you'll have to add a translation here... Google translate came up with "On the contrary, buying doubt" which doesn't really help me understand your point... :)

Comment: I tried to change *In dubio pro reo* (*When in doubt, for the accused*) a bit to turn it into *When in doubt, against editing* or *When in doubt, don't edit*.

Comment: @AnneDaunted, Ah thanks! That's one of the reasons why I asked and I didn't edit immediately. Once my doubts would have been cleared I might have done so. ;-) But someone else didn't doubt and did. Now, let's see where it takes the question ... I might self-answer if it works or not ;-)

Comment: But unlike on TWP, we should be more careful on IPS, IMHO. By removing ranty parts, we may (accidentally) remove explanations for the OP's wish. Here for example the *I can't be untrue to myself by* bit. Btw, I know that you didn't edit it.

Answer (score 2):

I've handled things like this at TWP.  Tone makes all the difference.  In this one's current state, the OP comes across as less than sympathetic and, IMO, people are down-voting the tone.

Taking out the parts that make him look difficult will help.

EDITED TO ADD:

I removed the "I can't be untrue to myself" because it is irrelevant to any answer given.

at TWP, we tend to trim down anything that is a "rant" or details that are not relevant to any answers given.  It also makes the answers more generic so that anyone having a similar problem can get good advice.

Unless one's feelings are relevant to the answer, and ESPECIALLY if they make the OP look less than sympathetic, they should be removed because the only thing that doing otherwise will produce is down-votes for a question that actually has some core value.

"I don't have the same feelings for my boyfriend and I need to tell him" would be relevant to the question as it would be key to providing answers

"I don't feel right calling a MTF trans person 'she'" would not be relevant to an answer on how to address a MTF trans person.

So, as a general rule, eliminate the rants, and any **irrelevant** comments on how one feels in a question and it should be a good edit.

Comment: Your edit looks good, thank you! I'll remember it for next time.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I've seen posts go from -7 + to positive territory just by taking out ranty sections.  I hope this one reverses.