# Can you add “how-to-deal with a situation”, “advice” and “suggestion”?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

Can you please add these 3 tags? Because, I’d like to have permission to ask about “how to deal with....”

Comment: All 3 of those are essentially "What should I do"-Tags. which is off topic

Comment: How-to-deal also tends to tie to **intra**personal questions, which are also off topic.

Answer (score 3):

How-to-deal with a situation is off topic for the same reason as "what should I do" questions. It mostly boils down to having too little information to make a good decision.

The advice and suggestion are really similar in that they also imply "what should or do" or "what can I do". Although answers to such questions could be useful, in the majority of cases they won't. I expect questions like these to be closed for being "primarily opinion based"

Comment: Ok, then how about this tag “what should I do?”

Comment: @AlexA "What should I do" questions [are explicitly off-topic](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1310/are-what-should-i-do-questions-on-topic-here); we even have a [custom close reason](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2953/) for them.

Comment: I wouldn't be opposed to having a "what should I do" tag so we can find off-topic questions faster... ;)