# If a question type is off topic then should it be used on the tour page?

Tags: discussion, scope

The question:

[Are “what should I do” questions on topic here?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1310/are-what-should-i-do-questions-on-topic-here) On IPS.

> Over at Workplace.se, they have an off-topic close reason for "what to
>   do" questions, because it attracts opinion-based answers.

Top Answer:

> I think questions of the form: "here's my tale of woe; **what do I do
>   now?**" are too broad and opinion-based on many sites, especially here.

Second answer:

> Yes! Make a decision for me questions should be off topic.

Has apparently been decided fairly conclusivley that the issue is off topic.

- A recent debacle on English Language and Usage [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/481044/my-crush-have-a-crush-on-my-bf/481047?noredirect=1#comment1161223_481047) seems to amplify the point:

> This question would also be off-topic on IPS because "what do I do" is
>   off-topic there. It would be very helpful for everyone involved if you
>   familiarized yourself with a site before recommending people post
>   questions there. Thanks.

- However, the tour page for IPS contains the example question:

> I love the unicorns who hang out behind my kitchen, but they do tend
>   to eat rather a lot of the daisies. **What can I do about this?**

- Which is **not** I think supposed to be regarded as off topic.

**I find myself baffeld by a seeming contradiction here, can anyone clarify the point, is it simply a matter of a pedantic choice of phrasing between "what can I do?", "what do I do?" and "what to do?", some or other being more or less acceptable.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention! The unicorn question is a generic example question that shows up on the tour page for any StackExchange site that hasn't customized it. "What should I do" questions are definitely off-topic here, and we even have a [custom close reason](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2957/3171) for such questions.

[This meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163947/what-determines-the-questions-available-for-selection-in-the-tour-page) explains the limitations of the tour page:

> The posts have to be short, with at least two short answers (<=400 chars). They also shouldn't have any crazy formatting.

Unfortunately due to the nature of posts here, most of them are long and with longer answers, so we only had [one available choice](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/30/). I've just updated [the tour page](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/tour) now to show that one.

Comment: Perhaps we should work on getting another in place, as we're not an editorial service either... But for now, this should do better than the unicorn question, I guess.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Another site decided to [create an artificial question with an artificial vote count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318280/historically-locked-question-reaching-hot-network-questions-via-vote-manipulation) in order to have an eligible question. The only issue was that the artificial question ended up hitting Hot Network Questions. (Not that that's an issue for this site.)

Comment: I just browsed to the [tour page](/tour) and I'm still seeing the generic unicorns question. https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3665/tour-page-still-shows-generic-unicorns-eating-daisies-question