# Tour page still shows generic "unicorns eating daisies" question despite supposedly being changed by a moderator

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tour-page

The site [tour page](/tour) shows an example question for the purposes of showing how the Q&A model works. On most sites that haven't configured it, it shows a generic "unicorns eating daisies" question.

Per a prior [community discussion](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3494/if-a-question-type-is-off-topic-then-should-it-be-used-on-the-tour-page), it was determined that this generic question was not suitable as it is a "what should I do" question, which is explicitly off-topic here. It was [supposedly changed by a moderator](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3495/11936) to [this question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/30/).

However, I just navigated to the tour page and it still shows the generic "unicorns eating daisies" question. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did indeed change the question on the tour page earlier, as I said in the post you linked.

Since then, [the question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/posts/30/revisions) and [one of its answers](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/posts/40/revisions) were edited.

As a result, it's no longer eligible to be displayed on the tour page, and IPS has no other questions that fit [the criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163947/what-determines-the-questions-available-for-selection-in-the-tour-page), so apparently the system has automatically reverted the tour page to the default "unicorn" question.

Comment: What do you think of the "artificial question" idea, in my comment on the question?

Comment: Also, I'm preparing a Meta.SE post asking for a better way to make tour questions, without having to resort to the tricks employed in the prior case.

Comment: I think that should be its own separate meta discussion, so we can discuss whether we want to do that here and what to make the question.

Comment: Started a discussion here: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/creating-a-question-for-use-in-the-tour-page