# Closure of question on people who work too slowly

Tags: discussion

[This comment](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/13019/how-do-you-convince-someone-that-theyre-working-too-slowly?noredirect=1#comment53285_13019) stated:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we cannot advise anyone on how to get someone to do something.

But I've since rewritten it to [fit this site](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2620/2423). If there is another unstated reason for closing my question, can I please be told to help me improve?

Comment: *DO NOT* edit questions after they've been answered to drastically change what they are about.

Comment: @Catija Isn't this the nature of editing questions? I've edited it again, but haven't drastically changed it. The original title will mislead.

Comment: You changed it from being about one question to being about a completely different question. No, that's not what editing is about.

Answer (score 8):

Please, in future, give an edited question time to get reviewed by the community before asking about it on meta. You posted this at the same time you edited it.

Regardless "how can I cope" is not an interpersonal skill. It's asking for what you can do internally... that's intrapersonal... so it's now off topic here.

Answer (score 3):

It's been hardly any time since your questions have been edited. When a question that has been put on hold has been edited for the first time it is automatically put into a queue where users with sufficient reputation can vote to reopen it if they find that it is a good fit for this site. Especially during off hours it takes time for enough users to review the queue.

Looking at the edits you have made to your most recent batch of questions I don't think either of them worth reopening in their current form.

Asking "how can I cope?" is a personal skill not an **inter**personal skill.

Asking "What can I do?" is far to broad a question. Every human action is an acceptable answer.