# Why does this question involve interpersonal skills?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Both of my girlfriends want a conventional monogamous marriage](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/10683/both-of-my-girlfriends-want-a-conventional-monogamous-marriage)

It took me some time to figure out what Interpersonal Skills are, and I'm still not very sure I really know it now.

IPS seems to be broader to me than they are to others.

But in this case I can't see why this question isn't closed... Any one can tell me ?

Comment: It will be easier to explain it to you if we know where you're comming from. Can you [edit] your question to contain your reasoning for why you think this question should be closed. Alternatively you could post an answer to this question arguing why you think the question should be closed.

Comment: Because it's a what-should-I-do type of question. And it's opinion based, etc, etc, you can take almost all the arguments that are used for question to be closed in IPS. But for some reason this one isn't...

Answer (score -2):

Whether or not it is about IPS, I think the question could clearly be improved.

This meta answer clearly outlines some viable alternatives for how this question could be framed in an IPS friendly way: [What is the difference between a "convince" question and a good question?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2618/what-is-the-difference-between-a-convince-question-and-a-good-question#answer-2620)

> **Convince Questions:**
>
> How do I convince dad to buy me a new pc?
>
> How do I make people stop forcing drinks on me?
>
> How can I change my friend's political opinion?
>
> **IPS Acceptable Alternatives:**
>
> How can I most effectively approach my
> dad about a new pc?
>
> How do I assert an alcohol-free lifestyle choice?
>
> How can I have a mutually respectful discussion with a friend of mine
> with different political opinions?

Comment: Thanks god we can see the edits... So we agree on the fact that this one should be closed down or at least be voted down.

Comment: @YCN- Downvotes shouldn't be used just because a question is off topic. Downvotes and close votes are orthogonal to each other. The reason that they both exist is because they're there to do two separate things, to keep people on topic by closing off topic questions, and to indicate public sentiment about how useful a question or answer is. The question has been put on hold so there's no reason for further action.