# Are INTRApersonal questions allowable on this site or is this strictly interpersonal?

Tags: discussion, scope

As the title suggests, I was looking to ask an intrapersonal question and was wondering if this would be the appropriate site? I understand this SE is more about sociology than psychology but there is no SE as of yet that covers the psychology aspect of life.

It's mostly about wanting to regain a part of you that was lost as you grew older. As an example, say that you want to believe in santa clause again. But no matter how hard you try to re-establish this belief, it simply won't happen because you have reached a level of critical thinking that does not allow you to. But you really want to regain those beliefs or at least live like how you did in the past because you found that during those times, you were at peace with life.

Comment: What kind of question(s) are you thinking about? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @AnneDaunted It's mostly about wanting to regain a part of you that was lost as you grew older. As an example, say that you want to believe in santa clause again. But no matter how hard you try to re-establish this belief, it simply won't happen because you have reached a level of critical thinking that does not allow you to. But you really want to regain those beliefs or at least live like how you did in the past because you found that during those times, you were at peace with life.

Comment: Related: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/intrapersonal-problem-which-interferes-with-interpersonal-relationship-on-topic

Comment: @ggiaquin you are welcome to join us in [chat]. We have users that might be able to listen and give some thought.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think it would be a good fit.

The expertise to understand/resolve internal, psychological problems is very different than someone who is a keen observer in the ways of social mores and interactions. I don't want to say that one needs more study than the other… but yeah, I'd definitely want to assure there were more experts/professionals studied in psychology before we tackled the subject.

By and large, not the same subject; not the same site.

Comment: Robert, is there a site that this type of discussion would be on topic? I haven't been able to find a fit but I would imagine there should be one considering we have an interpersonal site.

Comment: @ggiaquin This type of Q&A doesn't really support "discussion". We have [Cognitive Sciences](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com) for psychology, but that's more of an academic perspective than a source for self help.  Unfortunately, I don't think there will ever be a site like that — Interpersonal Relationships was the first — and it doesn't seem like questions dealing with deeply personal self-help issues are a good fit for platform that does not support the conversations these subjects deserve, Without that empathy and support, this is more a source of frustration than a "better Q&A solution."