# "question seems a little too opinionated for this site"

Tags: feature-request

I noticed this sentence used (copy / paste) for several posts, and it is incredibly bad. My dictionary says:

**Opinionated**: Characterized by **conceited assertiveness** and **dogmatism** (example: An **arrogant and opinionated** man).

This is used for posts that are **opinion-based**. **Opinionated** is something totally different from opinion-based. It is an insult.

Can someone change this template that is copied / pasted repeatedly and change the wording to use proper English that means what it says instead of insulting people.

(Tagged feature request because template text used by multiple users is a feature of the site, and this particular feature needs fixing).

Comment: [These are the more common comment templates](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3262/comment-templates) I'm not seeing the one you're referring to there.

Answer (score 4):

I'm to blame. I wrote that canned comment myself, basing it on the "primarily opinion-based" close reason. I use the [AutoReviewComments](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments) user script to post that. (I wasn't aware of the meta post where such canned comments are gathered, so that's why you don't see it there.)

My excuse is that the main site I participate in is Meta Stack Exchange, not here. There we often (mis)use the term "opinionated" to mean "opinion-based". My main goal with that canned comment is to better imply the *reason* why "What should I do?" questions are off-topic, other than "the community decided so". That's my excuse and I'm sticking to it, but I apologize for the incorrect perception of that comment resulting from a wrong definition.

Anyway, I've since modified the template in my user script to use the word "subjective" in it instead of "opinionated". (I'm unable to modify older comments.) If you can think of a better word, especially one with a lower English level, please comment.

Comment: Thanks for linking me here from my previous comment. I doubt you will find one word which clearly describes a question as primarily inviting opinion-based answers, but what do you think of some alternatives like 'not focused enough' or 'too broad-brush at present' to encourage people to distil their question down to something which is a better fit?