# Should we use chat to give non-IPS solution, instead using comment?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

Some question might have optimal/best solution with non-IPS approach.

Answer is not the place to post non-IPS solution (if the [answer solely suggest non-IPS solution](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1471/what-to-do-with-answers-that-arent-related-to-interpersonal-skills)).

However, some might want to help with non-IPS approach. After the policy to not allow non-IPS answer is implemented, I've noticed that people start giving non-IPS answer in comments.

What should we do with non-IPS suggestion in the comments?

Should we encourage people to move the discussion about non-IPS approach to chat? If yes, would general chat work? Or create a new chatroom?

What if the non-IPS solution just need one comment and there's no discussion?

Answer (score 4):

> What should we do with non-IPS suggestion in the comments?

Comments are for requesting clarification or suggesting improvements to a post, not for answers/suggesting alternatives to an answer. These comments should be deleted.

> Should we encourage people to move the discussion about non-IPS approach to chat? If yes, would general chat work? Or create a new chatroom?

So, I'd say we don't encourage people to have long discussions and have a mod move that to chat. I have to look into what goes into moving comments to chat. Maybe they have some guidelines on what should be in a chat and what not.

Personally, I can only move my 'own' comment discussions to chat (I believe). And that will not remove the comments from underneath an answer, but only copy them to chat.

If someone makes a comment suggesting a non-ips solution beneath one of my posts, I flag that as 'no longer needed' and have it removed. If I don't engage, there won't be a long discussion, and no need to move comments to chat.

Discussing non-IPS solutions in the general chatroom isn't helpful if the OP of a question isn't present there. Just as moving a comment thread underneath an answer won't be of much use if the OP never visits that room.

> What if the non-IPS solution just need one comment and there's no discussion?

Again, comments are for requesting clarification or suggesting improvements, not for answering.

If we allow 1 comment, why not allow the other comment as well?

e.g. if we allow:

> You could also wear headphones.

Means we should also allow

> You could plug your ears with wax.

This would basically lead to humongous comment threads of non-IPS suggestions, some may be ridiculous but can't be downvoted because they are a comment.

**Comments that aren't requesting clarification or suggesting an improvement to a post are not welcome here.**

Comment: I only disagree with forbidding discussion of non-IPS soution in the chat. We have many discussion in chat which does not relate to IPS.

Comment: @Vylix hmm, true. I have to look into what goes into moving comments to chat (which is btw a thing only a mod can do). Maybe they have some guidelines on what should be in a chat and what not...

Comment: Agreed with pretty much all of it. I'd have added the same.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell well, moving comments to chat can only be done **once**, so I guess we should not use that feature. Instead, ask them to move the discussion to chat, then wait 1 hour (or immediately) delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think IPS is the place to provide non-IPS related solutions at all.

If people come here, they want an interpersonal solution to their problem. This site is *for* building a high quality collection of interpersonal solutions.

It is *not* a discussion forum. The comments are *not* for discussion. I don't really think that there is a place here to "discuss non IPS Solutions" to IPS questions.

Answer (score -1):

Comments are not the place to give a non-IPS suggestion but while thinking out loud whether the non-IPS comment might be moved to chat, ***you might have found a good and acceptable  way to help OP***, because 'chat' as defined at Stack Exchange certainly has greater scope for presenting things that are  only peripherally on topic or even outright off topic, such as a non-IPS solution.

In fact there is nothing (*except their individual "IPS conscience"*) stopping anyone from posting a non-IPS solution in the general chat section but how to inform OP if the OP is not a regular participant on the chat pages?  It might well be possible (though you need to try it out to be sure) to post a non-IPS suggestion for OP in the **general chatroom** and hyperlink it into a comment under OP's question.

That means OP will be contacted through the comment even if they never otherwise visit chat, and they can then follow the link to the relevant chat message even a few hours later. **Most importantly the non-IPS solution will not appear as a comment or an answer in the main page.** Will this work in practice? Members please try it out and give your valuable feedback in the comments section!

**Update**: I tried it out right here as a comment:

> Testing... Hello @OP, I have left a possible solution (not IPS) in chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41337146#41337146

Useful tip from @Magisch to copy the hyperlink of your own chat message soon after posting:

> click the lil arrow dropdown on the left end of your message and copy the link adress of the "permalink"

It works in practice to the extent that you can actually leave a (non IPS suggestion in a) chat message and hyperlink it into a comment for OP that does not display the non IPS solution on the main page, and OP can actually follow the link and read the non IPS chat message.

Will this work a few hours later? I THINK SO. But will this method be accepted by moderators and the community? Stay tuned for downvotes and updates here!

**Update 2:** as I expected, some users don't approve of this method because

> This would basically be leaving an answer in comments in a very cumbersome way, while comments are for asking clarification or suggesting improvements – Tinkeringbell

So I was looking for another way to leave a chat message for OP, completely bypassing the question page, and was kindly helped out by a tip from @NVZ:

> There is an option under the "chat profile" of a user to "invite" them to a room or start a new room with them, and they will be notified just like any other notification. They can then join or ignore the room. Visit https://chat.stackexchange.com/users and search there for the required user's name to get to their chat profile, which is different from the normal SE profile.

I have tested this method and it works but some members expressed the concern in the general chatroom that users will begin to 'misuse chat' for this purpose. However it is a nonsense to think that what is off-topic by the strict regulations of the main site will be automatically off-topic for chat, and I have often seen some extremely irrelevant things being discussed on the Awkward Silence. It's OK because chat as used on SE has a very wide scope for expressing ideas and sharing information even remotely relevant to the site and the issues asked here. It is certainly a place to give OP a non IPS tip that can't be posted on the main site.

So thanks for the expert information @NVZ! ***I am not going to give a non-IPS suggestion to any OP but it is useful to know that there is a proper way to contact a member without posting any off topic answer or comment, if anybody wants to give them a non-IPS suggestion in a chat message.***

Comment: Testing... Hello @OP, I have left a possible solution (not IPS) in chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41337146#41337146

Comment: It works in practise to the extent that you can actually leave a (non IPS suggestion in a) chat message and hyperlink it into a comment for OP  *that does not display the non IPS solution on the main page*, and OP can actually follow the link and read the non IPS chat message. Will this work a few hours later? I THINK SO. But will this method be accepted by moderators and the community? Stay tuned for updates here!

Comment: This would basically be leaving an answer in comments in a very cumbersome way, while comments are for asking clarification or suggesting improvements

Comment: Chat does have leeway for posting a non-IPS suggestion. The comment is only meant to draw the attention of an OP who does not frequent the chat section. Ideally we would prefer not to use comments for this purpose, since comments are for asking clarification or suggesting improvements. You know any better way of bringing OP to chat @Tinkeringbell?

Comment: @EnglishStudent There is an option under the "chat profile" of a user to "invite" them to a room or start a new room with them, and they will be notified just like any other notification. They can then join or ignore the room. Visit https://chat.stackexchange.com/users and search there for the required user's name to get to their chat profile, which is different from the normal SE profile.

Comment: Thanks for the information @NVZ! I am not going to give a non-IPS suggestion to any OP but it is useful to know there is a proper way to contact a member to give them a chat message.