# With no reputation, can I somehow answer a blocked question because it attracted low-quality or spam answers?

Tags: support, answers

I wanted to answer a [question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/9513/how-do-i-stress-that-having-children-is-not-an-option-when-picking-a-date) but it become blocked by community because it has attracted low-quality or spam answers. I do not have 10 reputation to answer it, since I am not that active on this site and did not get any reputation except association bonus.
Yet I honestly believe my answer is good answer for that question.

Is there a way to answer it other than raising my reputation on site?

To be specific:

Question is about

> dating someone and make him aware you do not want kids ever.

My answer would be something like

> Show him you are proactive - talk about (and think yourself about) permanent contraception (by OP, I think vasectomy scares lot of men, including me). People change in time, so there is no other way stating your opinion as final.

I believe it is good answer because no answer mentioned permanent contraception, that is strong sign of not wanting kids.

I do not want to answer in comments.
I do not feel asking, answering other question ad hoc would be good.

Some sub questions:
Does reputation on meta site count?
Is there a way to get attention of OP or moderators so I can post my answer?

In the end I will sooner or later add this answer to that question If someone will not state my view, but it will take some time to gain reputation. I will probably rise my reputation by some tag editing.

Comment: Your proposed answer is what we here call as "non-IPS" solution, which would not do well on this site. There may already be such answers, but they're deleted, so you won't see them.

Comment: While I truly believe that people and their views change over time, that would be considered as not a direct answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Good point about "non-IPS". This is why I am not too keen to ask/answer something, since I am not that good in IPS. But here I directly did not say "go and have operation". What I was thinking is more about talking about this ultimate decision like "I do not want kids in future so I might have an operation". Simply talking about it would be sign that OP take his position seriously. Quite frankly, thinking about such operation might change stance the OP has to less radical.

Comment: There are 18 answers there (2 were deleted for being non-IPS). Are you sure none of them mentioned what you're thinking of answering? It's not that hard to get one upvote on your answer. Do you think you can answer some other question to get that upvote, and thereby get past the protection barrier?

Comment: @NVZ Yes I did read all answers. None of them mention it. As I wrote I will sooner or later get some reputation, but I do not want to do something ad hoc since it could backfire.

Comment: Like NVZ suggested, there was previously an answer suggesting to have an operation, but it was deleted for not giving an interpersonal solution (it said basically "get an operation and then tell them you are infertile"). I do see how yours is different, so I think it might be ok *if* you focus on how to have the discussion and explaining why you think this would work, etc. BTW thank you for refraining from answering in comments :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is not blocked, or locked. It is currently "protected" to prevent answers from new users. Read more about question protections on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52764/309993).

To overcome this barrier, the only way is to participate on the *main* IPS site and gain 10 rep. The association bonus 100 does not count.

You may gain 10 by getting 1 upvote on your answer to another question, or 2 upvotes to a question you ask here, or get 5 suggested edits accepted.

Reading the snippet of your potential answer, I sense that it might turn out to be a non-IPS solution that a majority of the users have decided is not a good fit for the site.
Read [about non-IPS answers](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1471/345) and other related discussion before you answer questions here. Good luck!

Comment: In the guidelines about protection there is `Do unprotect questions that aren’t currently attracting a lot of attention and don’t have a long history of unproductive answers.`. Is this done at least sometimes when question cools down?

Comment: @Piro We do unprotect some questions once the heat is gone.