# Tell me **exactly** what is wrong with this Answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Another Answer was wrongly deleted with not justification.

[How to show appreciation to colleague?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/20276/how-to-show-appreciation-to-colleague/20279?noredirect=1#comment81116_20279)

You will note in the comments that the Commenter **freely admitted they missed details in the Question.**

One valid comment was addressed with an Edit even though this same point is not addressed in any other Answer.

Comment: @sphennings Nope.  As noted, commenter openly admitted they misread the question.  Still, no one ever tells me why the Answer is deleted.  No rule or policy issue has ever been noted.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect to gain by asking this again. Comments were left explaining what was wrong with the answer and what needed to be done to get the question undeleted. When you have asked similar questions previously people have **repeatedly** explained site policy to you and offered suggestions on how to edit your question to to comply with them. What makes you think that asking again will result in a different result?

Comment: @sphennings No.  As I clearly state, Noon admitted to misreading the question.  how am I supposed to address a Comment that is not based on the actual question?  This happens ever time, they comment, I point out that the comment is not supported by the question, Delete.  And no, not actual site policy has ever been offered to explain this.

Comment: @EmC Ok, then tell me how the other Answers are based on 'expertise'.  And I quoted the specific pointing out where Noon misread the Question.  Seems I'm the only one to really read and understand the Question.

Comment: It seems that you are operating under the false assumption that there exists a mysterious canonical text containing a list of all the rules for this site. That isn't the case. We have better things to do than create such a pedantic document and litigate every single edge and corner case. We're all adults here and the expectation is that common sense and discussion can be used to establish policy. If policy was unclear it is likely that there would have been dissenting answers when you asked this question previously. In short consensus on meta is site policy.

Comment: @sphennings If there are no rules, fine, stop using them to justify deleting Answers.  Doing so is no different than a parent using "because I say so".  If were all adults here, stop treating member and Askers like children.  Give them some credit.  And BTW, the lack of clears rules is exactly why each case has to be litigated separately.

Comment: Note the repeated links to discussions about site policy on meta. While they aren't codified into legalese we do expect people to follow them. If something seems unclear perhaps you could ask a question requesting clarification on some specific point.

Comment: @Johns-305 Everything you've posted on meta has been met with in depth explanations and links to our policies, which you keep ignoring in favor of posting *more* passive aggressive content.  Until your questions on meta show research, or listening, effort, I'm also VTC this as a dupe.

Comment: A quick sidenote: this is the **third** time now you've posted with a title demanding we give you something. I see you have some experience on StackOverflow, so I'll use an analogy there. Imagine a newer SO user with 500 rep posts a new question with the title "Tell me **exactly** what is wrong with my code." I don't know about you, but I'd expect it to get downvotes by the bushel. I'd **highly** suggest that you approach contributions to meta like any other site: that is, by being polite and respectful and attempting to have an open conversation as opposed to making demands and blaming users.

Comment: @JessK. Sorry, please follow the whole story.  No one is able to tell me how my Answer do not meet this criteria.  Never.  And I will continue to demand explanation for wrongfully deleted Answers until some can explain this.  It's like taking someone to jail and mere referring to the Federal Register when they ask what they did.

Comment: @scohe001 And it will continue until the Deleters are able to fully justify their actions.  They have never been able to explain exactly how my Answers do not meet the criteria.  Follow all threads, you'll see that's quite clear.  If you look at my history, please, it's brilliant ;), you will see that I am happy to address specific issues when they are justified.  Sorry, but the Moderators have not been able to do that.

Answer (score 7):

The comments explain this.

One user mentioned:

> And why this won't be seen as too friendly (a personalized gift does sound friendly to me as you took the time to really think about it) and won't be seen as rude by the other coworker?

and

> I would still like to know how spendy time thinking of a personal gift to offer will be seen as less weird than spending money? Also, you didn't address the "rude to other" part of the question, which is the main reason for my downvote.

As you repeatedly left the same passive-aggressive comment at that user, I stepped in. I told you:

> [Our answer policy](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3266/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer/) calls for [expertise, not opinion](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3271/) (provide sources) and [explaining which specifics of the question affect your answer](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3273/).

The steps to undeletion are:

1. **Read those posts. That is the policy that you keep asking about, and which others have linked multiple times.**
2. Edit your answer to respond to those comments.
3. Then you can raise a flag to have the mods look at it.

Comment: Ok, then why aren't the other Answer held to this?  Consistency.  I expect them to be Deleted immediately.

Comment: @Johns-305 You don't yet have the privileges to see the deleted answers of others; if you did, you'd find that many questions have indeed had answers that didn't meet standards and were subsequently deleted. If you see other answers that you think *don't* meet the site's standards but have not been deleted, please flag them, but make sure - above all - you understand what we're looking for in answers before flagging or writing more of your own.

Comment: @Johns-305 There's two other answers. One explains a personal experience in a similar situation and how OP could apply that to their situation, so it seems fine to me, although other users can still request improvements if they find something is missing. The other does not currently so I've left a comment on it, now that I've had time to read through it.

Comment: @EmC I have to point out, my Answer was Deleted after ~7 hrs and it's nowbeen 18 hours since your comment on the other Answer yet it has not been Deleted.  Can you explain the difference?