# Should we start deleting old, closed question?

Tags: discussion, questions

The other day, I asked [this question](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3443/21067) about re-tagging closed questions and, judging by the answers, my conclusion isn't that we should re-tag them, but that we should *delete* most of them.

Here are some interesting links that talk about deleting questions:

[When should I vote to delete a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58842/when-should-i-vote-to-delete-a-question/59054#59054)

[The Value of Downvoting, or, How Hacker News Gets It Wrong](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/09/the-value-of-downvoting-or-how-hacker-news-gets-it-wrong/)

This second link says this:

> Minor forms of bad behavior encourage worse ones: that a neighborhood with lots of graffiti and broken windows becomes one where robberies occur.

So, should we start deleting or old, closed questions? Or maybe only does who [doesn't have answer](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=Newest&q=closed%3Ayes%20answers%3A0)?

Comment: Some closed questions will get deleted by the system automatically. So there's that.

Comment: @NVZ Yes, but what about the upvoted one that are closed with no answers?