# Can we close question 10333 (About licking spoons) until it is improved?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

[How do I tell someone that a cultural practice is unsanitary and they should stop?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/10333/1599)

This was closed as too broad, as it initially mentioned three different situations. When I cast the last close-vote this morning, that was already edited down, **BUT** as I pointed out in a comment, there was some critical information lacking...

[**It doesn't include culture tags**](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/should-we-tag-our-questions-by-cultural-region). We don't know what culture the OP is living in, and more importantly, we don't know in which culture licking spoons is acceptable behaviour.

So, there's no way for me to answer this question, since I don't know who I am going to be telling 'don't lick the frigging spoon, that's disgusting'.

What culture is the spoon-licker coming from? What should I keep in mind, would my Dutch directness offend the person and should I thus refrain from answering?

**Can we re-close this question until the OP has added this info?**

Comment: I agree with you that the question is still *too broad*, since we neither know the OP's cultural background nor that of their guests. That's why I cast a close vote. After all, the most precise information we got is [peanut butter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peanut_butter)...

Comment: I edited and specified cultures, and in a comment, I specified any food in a jar or any container that they double-dip. I did not want to be that specific because many consider that kind of detail bashing and/or me ranting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The question was edited and no longer needs to be closed.**

For next time: please don't reopen questions that still need improving.

Look through the comments if there are still open items before voting. 
If you disagree improvements are needed, it would be nice to provide some feedback to the people that took the time to try and ask for an improvement to know that they're overdoing it. 
Reopening without having all comments addressed doesn't provide much incentive to improve a question further.

It's bothersome to have to write a meta to get questions up to shape with simple guidelines like culture tags.