# Why was this question about building a rapport with clients closed?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/18575/how-do-i-build-a-rapport-with-someone-i-find-really-boring-and-have-nothing-in-c) asking how to build a rapport with clients with whom the OP shares few (if any) common interests was closed as Too Broad.

[The help center](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) states that on topic questions should be specific enough to be answered, with the following criteria for being specific.

- **Cultural context.** Culture may include your geographic location and/or the type of setting (e.g. a specific workplace or social group). See [Should we tag our questions by (cultural) region?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4/378) for more information.
- **Who is involved and their relationship to you** - how you interact with a spouse vs coworker vs employee is vastly different.
- **What you've already tried,** if anything, and what effect that approach had.
- **Your priorities for the outcome.** In addition to resolving the immediate issue, this may include goals such as preserving or improving your relationship with the other person(s), having your feelings acknowledged, spending less time on the issue, etc. If any of your goals might conflict with one another, please rank them.

The question has:

- Cultural context - there's not much other than it being a client based work environment
- Who is involved - the OP and their clients
- What you've tried - OP has tried making small talk about common things (sports, weather, family, etc), but has found limited overlap in interest with the clients
- Priorities for outcome - OP wants to establish a good relationship with the client (to the point of potential repeat business from the clients)

The question went through review and had 3 votes to leave open compared to only one close vote, which means it picked up 3 close votes (other than the one that kicked it to the queue) organically.

What makes this question too broad, and what needs to be changed in order to get it re-opened?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the question.  As I've mentioned before the ability to cast a close vote is given too early to too many, and so many reasonable questions are closed by those who seem to find joy in exclusion, and rarely reopened by those of us who prefer diversity.

Comment: We need just 2 more votes to reopen.

Comment: @AlexL This stack has had problems in the past with questions getting into a cycle of close/reopen without any edits because there were different opinions of what was on topic. I hesitate to vote to reopen until a discussion has been had about why the question was closed.

Comment: @Rainbacon Ohh, I see.... Got it. (I am new here).